# set values from outside the report to a jasper report

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am going to generate reports using jasper reports. For that, my plan is,

- create the `jrxml` file as needed using `iReport` tool.
- set the values required from out side the report. (I mean if I have a variable called `name="james"` in my `java` program set that variable to a text field in the report)
- then create the report and generate the pdf.

What I need to know is the possibility of this. Can I set my variables into the fields in my `jrxml` file? If it is possible, How can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What I need to know is the possibility of this. Can I set my variables into the fields in my jrxml file?

Basically, yes.

You need to define the parameter as a "Parameter" type in the report, then supply the parameter as the "Text Field Expression" on the form in the format `$P{...}`

[image: Prameters]

Then, when you want to fill the report, you need to do is create a `Map` of some kind, each key in the map should be the name of parameter your defined in the report, for example...

```
Map<String, Object> mapParameters = new HashMap<String, Object>(5);
mapParameters.put("USER_NAME", name);

JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, mapParameters);
```

Answer (score 0):

it resolved !!

```
para.put(<key>,<value>);
para.put(<key>,<value>);
para.put(<key>,<value>);

JasperFillManager.fillReportToFile(jr, para, new JRemptyDataSource());
```

if you don't write  new JRemptyDataSource() a message will appear that the document has no pages 
and inside your report create a field and in field expression put your parameter (the parameter name should have the same key value )

Answer (score 0):

I got answer

```
     parameters.put("ReportTitle", "List of Contacts");
     parameters.put("Author", "Prepared By Manisha");

     JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(sourceFileName, parameters, new JREmptyDataSource());

     JRPdfExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
     exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(print));
     exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(outFileNamePDF));
     SimplePdfExporterConfiguration configuration = new SimplePdfExporterConfiguration();
     configuration.setMetadataAuthor("Petter");  //why not set some config as we like
     exporter.setConfiguration(configuration);
     exporter.exportReport();
```